# Is there a generic IDictionary implementation where IsFixedSize is True?

Tags: c#

I wonder if there is an implementation of IDictionary interface in the standard library that has property IsFixedSize == true.

In my code, I am using a Dictionary indexed by an enum, like this:

```
Dictionary<EMyEnum, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<EMyEnum, string>();
```

I always have values in the dictionary for all possible values of MyEnum, using a code like this:

```
    foreach (EMyEnum myEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EMyEnum)))
    {
        m_myDictionary.Add(myEnum, "");
    }
```

so my dictionary actually has a fixed size. It feels kind of 'wrong' to be using Dictionary for it and I am wondering if there is perhaps a better type I am missing.

I was looking in System.Collections.Generic and System.Collections namespaces but could not find anything suitable.

In response to one of the questions, the enum is just a bunch of values, like this:

```
enum EMyEnum
{
    meValue1,
    meValue2,
    meValue3
}
```

EDIT:

I have accepted supermem's answer as it is most to the point of the original question. To elaborate my original concern, an ordinary dictionary can have one of the keys/items deleted and then any code that relies on the fact that iterating over keys of the dictionary also iterates over all values of enum will be broken.

I understand that I can create a fixed size array but casting enums to ints is not that pretty, besides it would only work for contiguous enums (good enough in my case).

I think there is a good case for Dictionary that has enum values as keys and it is a pity that such a class does not ship with .Net.

Comment: What type of `enum` is it? Can we see the actual code for it?

Comment: It's not wrong. Move on.

Comment: Are values of your `enum` contiguous, or you assign them manually (e.g. as a list of powers of two)?

Comment: Dictionary<,> are sizable if you look at the documentation on MSDN so you could Initialize the Dictionary like this Dictionary<EMyEnum, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<EMyEnum, string>(100); that's called the Capacity

Comment: If it really bothers you, you could use an array of `KeyValuePair<>`. I wouldn't make the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no fixed size IDictionary implementations shipping with the CLR. (Except for the ReadOnly* sort, but not applicable to your problem.)

You can roll your own, but unless you have profiled this code and determined that the use of Dictionary presents a meaningful bottleneck (IMO, very rare), I'd say to keep it as is. You also have the benefit of readability as Dictionary is very well understood and easy to grok.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.5 actually introduces a new interface that sounds like it may be what you need, `IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Also, `IReadOnlyList<T>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the simple `enum` declaration and not explicitly assigning values to the elements, you could use just an array:

```
Array values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EMyEnum));
string[] myDictionary = new string[values.Length];
foreach (EMyEnum myEnum in values)
{  
    myDictionary[(int)myEnum] = "";
}
```

You could even wrap this approach in a custom class that treat the enum type as indexer, if you are bothered by those explicit casts to `int` everywhere:

```
class EnumDictionary<EnumType, ValueType>
{
    private readonly ValueType[] array = new ValueType[Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType)).Length];

    public ValueType this[EnumType index]
    {
        get { return array[Convert.ToInt32(index)]; }
        set { array[Convert.ToInt32(index)] = value; }
    }
}

EnumDictionary<EMyEnum, string> enumDictionary = new EnumDictionary<EMyEnum, string>();
foreach ( EMyEnum myEnum in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumType))
    enumDictionary[myEnum] = "";
```

Now, if this is *better* than using `Dictionary` or not is a completely different discussion.

Comment: Thanks. I started to write something along these lines, but then found out that System.Enum cannot be used as a constraint for generic. In your code, there should be a verification that EnumType is actually an Enum.

Comment: Precisely, System.Enum is not a valid constraint. This will break at run-time if a non-enum is given as the first type